# NerdTree window size is too large when current directory "."

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Every time I type

> vim .

and select some file, nerdtree is too large. there's a way to fix it?

[image: nerdtree is large]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set the size of windows like `let g:NERDTreeWinSize=20`

Answer (score 5):

This happened tom me, recently.

Try this

`let g:NERDTreeWinSize=31`

Then type

`:NERDTree`

Don’t use ‘:NERDTreeToggle`or`:NERDTreeFind`, as it doesn’t reset the window size. Only`:NERDTree does`